# Есть задача, где использованием таблицы частотного анализа нужно восстановить исходный текст

Tags: криптография

Дана таблица частотного анализа и с ее помощью нужно восстановить исходный текст. Пробовал брать таблицы встречаемости букв в русском языке, но они все отличаются и это не дало никаких результатов. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

41 33 88 63 __ 81 55 63 20 99 41 28 12 63 99 18
.
10 59 19 12 20 41 51 12 63 __ 99 63 12 41 95 33
.
10 ___ 22 63 55 63 67 41 63 22 ___
10 63 67 45 51 74 33 ___ 99 66 63 20 12 17 ___ 66 28 60 28 41 17
.
63 41 28 ___ 99 28 45 33 12 28 ___ 41 17 ___ 81 51 99 66 59 74 ___
20 70 28 44 17 74
,
41 17 ___ 81 55 63 66 17 12 28 41 44 33
,
63 88 55 17 67 63 10 17 10 60 33 35 99 20 ___ 63 66 ___ 44 63 99 66 55 17
.
44 55 51 19 63 22 ___ 41 17 ___ 67 33 22 12 33 ___ 66 63 41 44 28 22 ___ 99 12 63 33 22 ___ 12 33 25 17 12 ___ 41 33 45 17 10 41 63 ___
10 59 81 17 10 60 28 35 ___ 99 41 33 19
,
33 70 33 ___ 41 33____67 17 66 63 81 66 17 41 41 59 35
.
44 63 19 45 17 ___
81 12 33 41 41 59 33 ___ 81 63 55 17 10 41 20 12 28 99 18 ___ 99 ___ 44 63 99 66 55 63 22
,
55 17 67 45 17 12 17 99 18 ___
44 63 22 17 41 45 17 ___ 63 99 66 17 41 63 10 28 66 18 99 20 , 28___ 63 41 28
,
99 22 33 60 17 10 ___ 99 66 55 63 35 ___
99 66 63 12 81 28 12 28 99 18 ___ 10 63 67 12 33 ___ 44 63 99 66 55 17
,
81 63 67 45 63 55 63 10 17 12 28 99 18
.
41 63 ___ 66 33
,
41 33 ___ 63 66 10 33 66 28 10 ___ 41 17 ___ 81 55 28 10 33 66 99 66 10 28 20
,
63 66 10 63 45 28 12 28 ___ 19 12 17 67 17 ___ 10 ___
99 66 63 55 63 41 51
,
99 66 17 55 17 20 99 18 ___ 41 33 ___ 10 99 66 55 33 11 17 66 18 99 20 ___ 99 63 ___ 10 67 19 12 20 45 17 22 28
81 12 33 41 41 59 74
.
81 63 99 66 63 20 10 ___ 81 20 66 18 ___ 22 28 41 51 66
,
67 17 44 12 32 11 33 41 41 59 33 ___ 41 17 11 17 12 28 ___
63 66 74 63 45 28 66 18 ___ 63 66 ___ 44 63 99 66 55 17
.

Comment: **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос**. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, **что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи, а также ваши попытки её решения.

Comment: Частотный анализ плохо работает на коротких текстах. Используете словарь русского языка, благо в тексте много слов из 1 и 2 букв.